# SonarLint for Eclipse : Configure a custom SonarQube & language profile?

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint

Currently [SonarLint for Eclipse](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/) uses https://update.sonarlint.org/ as SonarQube instance.

Is there a way to configure a custom SonarQube url (with user authentication) for using your own default language profile ?

Could be very useful when you want more rules or you have configured some exclusions (mainly for external JavaScript libraries like JQuery, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too quick question, same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33214113/1485989) about IntelliJ, but with Eclipse answer.

This feature will be **supported in v2.0** ([SLE-26](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-26)).

---

However, there is a workaround ...

**Disclaimer** : This workaround is **not supported by SonarSource**, this is not a sustainable solution and **MUST not** deployed on a production environment. This is just a "technical stuff for fun", until feature supported officially by the plugin.

---

**Prerequisite** :

- [SonarQube **>= 5.2**](https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/) is required (tested with RC3)
- Use SonarLint **< v1.3** (strictly, see [SLE-24](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-24))
- SonarQube instance must not be secured (`sonar.forceAuthentication=false`)

The SonarLint uses Eclipse preferences for URL loading (See [SonarRunnerFacade](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-eclipse/blob/master/org.sonarlint.eclipse.core/src/org/sonarlint/eclipse/core/internal/jobs/SonarRunnerFacade.java#L38)), so could be overrided with [**pluginCustomization**](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html?cp=2_1_3_0).

In the `eclipse.ini` file (beside *eclipse.exe*), add in first :

```
-pluginCustomization
myPrefs.ini
-startup
...
```

With in `myPrefs.ini` file (beside *eclipse.exe/eclipse.ini*) :

```
# SonaQube - SonarLint URL override
org.sonarlint.eclipse.core/server_url=http\://localhost:9000
```

Comment: Alix, I was about to edit your answer but I feel it would be best if you would do it on your own => SonarSource won't support people who do this workaround because this can have multiple impacts now and in the future. Can you please add this notice to your answer? Thanks

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam : Done. Sorry. I can delete it or update the disclaimer if not enough precise.

Comment: Has somebody tried if this workaround is still working for SonarLint 1.3? I unfortunately can't try it for myself at the moment.

Comment: @Alex : Workaround tested with SonarLint 1.3 : **doesn't work**. Mainly because [SLE-24 : Stop depending on update.sonarlint.org](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-24). Only solution : watch & vote for [SLE-26](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-26).

Comment: That's sad :( It's going to be useless if quality profiles differ too much. Anyway thank you for testing!