# SonarLint - IntelliIdea download rule set from local sonarqube server

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

Getting SonarQube server 'https://update.sonarlint.org' can not be reached and data is not cached error because I am working in offline network on intelliJ ide.
But i must change the https://update.sonarlint.org url with my local sonar server url.
I think it can be done via change the content of sonarlint.xml. However, i could not find the file?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] .. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you use SonarLint, it needs to download analyzers and other information. After that, it will work offline.

Newer versions of SonarLint that are about to be released won't need to do this as they embed all the information they need.

Connecting to a SonarQube server to use it's analyzers and profiles is not yet officially supported.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291974/sonarlint-for-eclipse-configure-a-custom-sonarqube-language-profile
In the above link there is a tricky way for customizing the sonarqube server address. I wonder is there any such way for intelliJ until the new SonarLint version was released.

Comment: In the most recent versions of SonarLint that will be released this week, that won't work anymore as there won't be any connections at all.